# PHP remove the first index of an array and re-index

Tags: php, arrays, filter, sorting

I have an array like 
Array

```
(
    [0] => A
    [2] => B
    [4] => C
    [6] => D
)
```

I want to remove the first element and then re-index array to get the output

```
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => C
    [2] => D
)
```

Which PHP function i need to use?

---

**Update**

Input array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some Unwanted text
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => My belowed text
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => My loved quote
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

)
```

And the output should be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => My belowed text
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => My loved quote
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

)
```

Comment: Are you really need to reindex?

Comment: Please use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) so it's easier to test.

Comment: what for? What's the use of indexed array? Use `foreach()` and forget of indexing

Comment: i need to use foreach($myArray as $i=>$item) and then use $resultId =  $offset+$i

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With array_splice.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

```
php > print_r($input);
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [2] => B
    [4] => C
    [6] => D
)
php > array_splice($input, 0, 1);
php > print_r($input);
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => C
    [2] => D
)
```

Comment: Need to omit the third parameter array_splice($input, 0)

Comment: Use
array_splice($input, 1); // 1 is start index
to get this array ([0] => B, [1] =>C, [2] => D)

Comment: This is perfect if you want the actual array returned from the function, which is what I needed. Rather than using `array_shift` which returns the removed element for some reason known only to the PHP Devs?!?

Answer (score 36):

You can use

```
array_shift($array)
```

[Documentation for `array_shift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: i dont think array_shift would reindex the array

Comment: @lemon: the manual says otherwise: `All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero`

Comment: Please see the updated question, array_shift trick is not working if the values of passing array is again an array

Comment: Melmacian's answer with array_splice seems to be working, any one tried that?

Comment: For me (PHP 5.3.2, Ubuntu), it gives the output requested in the updated question.

Answer (score 3):

we can do it with `array_shift()` which will remove the 1st index of array and after that use `array_values()` which will re-index the array values as i did not get from the @User123's answer, try below one:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
                0 => "A",
                2 => "B",
                4 => "C",
                6 => "D"
            );
    array_shift($array);
    $array = array_values($array);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
```

**Output:**  check the output here https://eval.in/837709

```
Array
    (
        [0] => B
        [1] => C
        [2] => D
    )
```

**Same for your Updated Input array**

```
<?php
    $array = array(
                    0 => array(
                            0 => "Some Unwanted text",
                            1 => "You crazyy"
                        ),

                    2 => array(
                            0 => "My belowed text",
                            1 => "You crazyy"
                        ),

                    10 => array(
                            0 => "My loved quote",
                            1 => "You crazyy"
                        )

                );
    array_shift($array);
    $array = array_values($array);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array);
```

**Output:** check the output here https://eval.in/837711

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => My belowed text
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => My loved quote
            [1] => You crazyy
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cut the array as many many index as you want

```
$newArray = array_splice($oldArray, $startIndex, $lengthToSlice);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array(
0 => 'A',
2 => 'B',
4 => 'C',
6 => 'D'
);

unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($array);
print_r($array);
```

This is also another solution to this issue using `unset`

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => B
    [1] => C
    [2] => D
)
```