# Unset an array key, and restore the sorting

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP remove the first index of an array and re-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003259/php-remove-the-first-index-of-an-array-and-re-index)
>   [How to Remove Array Element and Then Re-Index Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array)

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);

unset($arr[0]);

print_r($arr);

//Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

What's the function called, so the output instead would be:

```
//Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Remove Array Element and Then Re-Index Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array) and [PHP remove the first index of an array and re-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003259/php-remove-the-first-index-of-an-array-and-re-index).

Comment: Ah it was re-index I was looking for :P

Answer (score 4):

You want to create a new array using [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values):

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
unset($arr[0]);
$arr = array_values($arr);

print_r($arr);
//Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )
```